# Text alignment at a particular position on the line

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I want to know how can I position text in a line which is neither entirely left aligned, nor right aligned, nor centrally aligned but is according to my choice. For example if I want a space of 10 cm before the text starts in that line how do I accomplish this?

I tried using `\hspace` but nothing is happening. Why is that?

Comment: "ordinary" spaces at the beginning of a line are ignored.  so use the starred version: `\hspace*{...}`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton That should be the answer (plus `\noindent`, of course)

Answer (score 2):

"ordinary" spaces at the beginning of a line are ignored.

to indent a line by `10cm`, start that line with

```
\noindent\hspace*{10cm}%
xxxx
```

the `\noindent` negates the usual paragraph indentation. 
the starred `\hspace*` is *not* ignored at the beginning of a line. 
since you want the distance to be precise, either start the text with
no typed space after the `\hspace*` or negate the end-of-line character
with a `%`, as shown here, and start the text on the next line.

Comment: what the need for %, when i add % the hspace is precise else not

Answer (score -1):

use `\hspace{}`

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
aaaa \hspace{20 mm} fff \hspace{5 mm} sssssssssssssss.

\end{document}
```

[image]